# What the heck do I do at the N7: Fuel Reactor mission

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've just landed on the planet & met Capt'n Riley. What the heck do I do after meeting her?

I can't venture out, I get killed by radiation.

I see this display for crane operation, I'm not sure how that works after fiddling with it..

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is use the crane in order to move the large box out of the way so you can proceed. This took me a little bit to figure out as well.

You need to hit the controls in this order:

- Move Left
- Activate
- Move Right
- Activate (though this is optional, as you don't *really* need to lower the box)

The video panel on the crane is a view of what's going on behind you, if that helps.

For a video of this, see this walkthrough:

Comment: perfect, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You use the crane operations panel to move the large container crates blocking your route outside, as shown on the screen.